FastAPI - listen to kafka in separate thread
I have a FastAPI application. The application subscribes to kafka-topic and handles messages (everything is working)
But when I added http endpoints, noticed that can't call the endpoints, because I am listen to kafka in infinite loop.
How to fix my code to enable http endpoints? I guess kafka subscription should work in separate thread
My code:
# main.py

from pathlib import Path

from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter


from app.api.v1.api import api_router
from app.core.config import settings


import logging

from aiokafka import AIOKafkaConsumer
from fastapi import FastAPI
import hashlib


log = logging.getLogger("uvicorn")

router = APIRouter(prefix="/kafka_consumer")


async def consume():
    """Consume and print messages from Kafka."""
    while True:
        async for msg in consumer:
            print("TODO: process msg ", msg.value.decode())



async def check_kafka() -> bool:
    """
    Checks if Kafka is available by fetching all metadata from the Kafka client.

    Returns:
        bool: True if Kafka is available, False otherwise.
    """
    try:
        await consumer.client.fetch_all_metadata()
    except Exception as exc:
        logging.error(f'Kafka is not available: {exc}')
    else:
        return True
    return False


@router.get("/healthz/ready")
async def ready_check() -> int:
    """
    Check the health of application dependencies.

    Returns:
        int: Representation of the HTTP status code for a successful response.
            - 200 if the server is ready.
            - 503 if the server is not ready.
    """
    readiness_probes = await asyncio.gather(
        *[component for component in [check_kafka(), http_client.is_ready()]],
    )
    ready = all(probe for probe in readiness_probes)
    status = HTTPStatus.OK if ready else HTTPStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
    return status


def create_application() -> FastAPI:
    """Create FastAPI application and set routes.

    Returns:
        FastAPI: The created FastAPI instance.
    """
    application = FastAPI(openapi_url="/kafka_consumer/openapi.json", docs_url="/kafka_consumer/docs")
    application.include_router(router, tags=["consumer"])
    return application


def create_consumer() -> AIOKafkaConsumer:
    """Create AIOKafkaConsumer.

    Returns:
        AIOKafkaConsumer: The created AIOKafkaConsumer instance.
    """

    return AIOKafkaConsumer(
        settings.kafka_topics,
        bootstrap_servers=settings.kafka_instance,
    )


app = create_application()
consumer = create_consumer()


@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    """Start up event for FastAPI application."""

    log.info("Starting up...")
    await consumer.start()
    log.info("Start consume")
    await consume()
    log.info("XXX Start app") # Don't see this log


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown_event():
    """Shutdown event for FastAPI application."""

    log.info("Shutting down...")
    await consumer.stop()


In addition to the link provided above (have a look at the references included as well), you might find this and this helpful as well.

Python is single threaded... I assume you want multiprocessing
